# Flutter: How can I play video from Uint8List

Tags: flutter

`AssetEntity asset = AssetEntity(id: photo.id);`

`Uint8List _video =
          await asset.thumbDataWithSize(photo.pixelWidth, photo.pixelHeight);`

using  video_player: ^0.10.9+1 package but in this I can't use Uint8List.
how can I play video?

Comment: There are several feature requests on github/flutter but no progress yet.